# Насколько на 2019 год актуальна обфускация C#?

Tags: c#, обфускация

Насколько на 2019 год актуальны методы обфускации c#. Имеет ли это смысл ? Какие конкретно инструменты использовать ? Что устарело, а что нет ? О топике много инфы в гугле, но актуальной - не хватает.

Мне нужно решить, как защитить свой c# продукт от дизассемблирования и декомпилирования, в связи с чем и возник вопрос.

Comment: Никак и нечем, у вас этого не получится сделать, раскрытие алгоритмов дело времени, а уж от дезасемблирования точно не спасет, даже темида.

Comment: от известных мне декомпиляторов, как ни странно, спасает массированное использование лямбда-выражений, expressions и всяких dynamic. Пробовал декомпилировать собственную dll с частично потерянными исходниками, в итоге пришлось восстанавливать по памяти. Ну и за такой код могут побить - и будут правы, читать его очень тяжело, а уж ошибки искать... А если серьезно - не занимайтесь ерундой. Патентуйте алгоритмы, если конечно они действительно уникальны или работайте по схеме SaaS: вся логика на вашем сервере, а клиент "тупой" терминал для работы с серверной логикой.

Comment: @rdorn , главное самому потом в таком коде не запутаться)

Comment: @rdorn я бы этот коментарий сделал бы ответом...

Comment: @rdorn, ну конечно, вы просто видимо ничего не в курсе об `CFR `, `Fernflower`, которые при правильном использовании и прямых руках, в легкую декомпильнут ваши лямбды, со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: @And конечно не в курсе, я этим почти не пользуюсь. А `Fernflower` уже умеет что-то кроме java? Если да, то гляну. С прямыми руками можно и без декомпайлера восстановить исходный код, вопрос времени и желания.

Comment: @Andrew таких вопросов, комментариев и ответов тут уже более чем достаточно... не вижу смысла.